Does server location and responsiveness affect SEO and how much?
I would like to ask if server location and responsiveness affect SEO and how much?
If I would like to reach for example Czech republic audience, is it better to have hosting with company having servers in Czech republic?
Is it possible that an inappropriate choice of hosting will move my website back by 10 bars?

I don't know what you mean by "back 10 bars".   My experience tells me that having servers closer to your audience will often improve SEO.  This is somewhat anecdotal and I posit that the quality of your content is more important.   Certainly very inappropriate hosting (like hosting on a system considered to be spammy/hacker friendly) will move SEO in the wrong direction.

Responsiveness is indeed important to SEO. Related questions: Should we improve time to first byte or Page Speed Insights score for SEO? and Will Google use field or lab data for ranking sites with core web vitals performance metrics?. Location is important insomuch as it improves responsiveness. Many sites choose to use a CDN to serve up part of their website from a server closer to the visitor's location, no matter where the visitor is located.
